# VB.Net - Check if File is .net binary

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, native, managed

How can I check with VB.Net if a the file

> C:\Documents\Test.exe

is a .net binary or if it is a native binary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a file is a .NET assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330032/checking-if-a-file-is-a-net-assembly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSDN on [How to: Determine If a File Is an Assembly (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173100.aspx):

> **How to programmatically determine if a file is an assembly**
>
> 1. Call the `GetAssemblyName` method, passing the full file path and name of the file you are testing.
> 2. If a `BadImageFormatException` exception is thrown, the file is not an assembly.

It even has an VB.NET example:

> ```
> Try 
>     Dim testAssembly As Reflection.AssemblyName =
>                             Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\System.Net.dll")
>     Console.WriteLine("Yes, the file is an Assembly.")
> Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>     Console.WriteLine("The file cannot be found.")
> Catch ex As System.BadImageFormatException
>     Console.WriteLine("The file is not an Assembly.")
> Catch ex As System.IO.FileLoadException
>     Console.WriteLine("The Assembly has already been loaded.")
> End Try
> ```

This isn't ideal since it uses exceptions for control flow.

I'm also not sure how it behaves in corner cases like the file being an assembly, but not supporting the current CPU architecture or if it targets an unsupported variant of the framework.

Comment: Thank you for your super fast reply :) Does this only work for .dll files are also for .exe files? And what does it mean, not an assembly? Not a managed file? (Native one) ? Would be cool if you can clarify that^^

Comment: @nexno Assembly means managed .NET executable and includes both `.exe` and `.dll` files.

Comment: +1 but What an horrible official solution provided by Microsoft, depending on exceptions and it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

Just I've write a generic usage function to complement @Loki answer:

```
''' <summary>
''' Determines whether an exe or dll file is an .Net assembly.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="File">Indicates the exe/dll file to check.</param>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if file is an .Net assembly, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
Friend Function FileIsNetAssembly(ByVal [File] As String) As Boolean

    Try
        System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName([File])
        ' The file is an Assembly.
        Return True

    Catch exFLE As IO.FileLoadException
        ' The file is an Assembly but has already been loaded.
        Return True

    Catch exBIFE As BadImageFormatException
        ' The file is not an Assembly.
        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```